# Deleted build agent workspaces assuming they would create new ones

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I always used to be able to safely delete a TFS Build agents workspace to combat issues of locked files and all sorts of things. Now in TFS 2015 Update 1 I have deleted and they will not automatically re-create, it insists on using the same one. It actually seems like it cannot create a workspace but is able to be assigned one. I say this because I have created a new build definition to build a new branch and I receive the same error:

```
2016-01-04T10:47:06.0521586Z Syncing repository: IsdDev (TFVC)
2016-01-04T10:47:06.0521586Z workspaceName=ws_7_14
2016-01-04T10:47:06.8832305Z ##[error]TF14061: The workspace ws_7_14;Project Collection Build Service does not exist.
2016-01-04T10:47:06.9342371Z ##[error]Prepare repository failed with exception.
```

How can I tell TFS to create a new workspace? I don't want to manually re-create them as there are many. I deleted using TFS Sidekicks (for 2013)

Thanks

Comment: Is the XAML or Task based build?

Comment: Try editing the build definition and going to the Repository tab and setting Clean to true.

Comment: Or maybe try restarted the build agent / Host Process.

Comment: I have done the opposite as it it was already set to true and I changed to false (and back to true) with no luck. Also restarted and sent updates to all build agents :(

Comment: Maybe a restart of the controller (or TFS itself)?

Comment: Can you just re-create the Workspace? You know the name and source mapping :)

Comment: Well, it gets created as user "Project Collection Build Service" followed by a guid. Not sure how I would create a workspace for a delegate user which I don't know credentials to. In addition there are around 100 or so that I'd have to do!

Comment: Interestingly, I did manage to get one of them working by changing the repo mappings. Unfortunately this same trick did not work for another build def

Comment: Can you try upping the verbosity of the build agent? Try passing "debug" as the first argument to the VsoAgent process. Or try setting: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TeamFoundationServer\14.0\DistributedTask\TraceLevel to a DWORD value of 4 (decimal).

Comment: I shall give this a try tomorrow. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: No joy unfortunately :(

Comment: Does it give additional information? You will need to restart the VsoAgent to pick up the registry change. It might log it to the Console - I don't have the src at work to check where it is logged it.

Comment: Not seeing any additional logging anywhere but after checking the agents logs and trying a number of different things, I have just reconfigured 1 agent with a new Id and it seems to be working. I'll do the rest (9) and then run all of my builds and see what happens!

Comment: Deleted my build agents and all workspaces associated with them. Then reconfigured using PowerShell as I did initially. Seems to have done the trick. A bit overkill but can't afford anymore time on it! Thanks for all your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to get this working. It's a bit overkill but I deleted all my build agents and all workspaces associated with them. Then I re-installed and re-configured using the PowerShell scripts. The Agents now have a new Id and subsequently creates new workspaces. Along with this, I had to delete the working directories so that the new workspaces didn't attempt to use the same ones.

I actually reconfigured my agents when I updated from TFS 2015 Update 1 **RC 1** to full Update 1. I think that during this transition I have muddled things up a bit.

Answer (score 3):

For us, deleting everything in the TFS cache folder solved the problem:

C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation

Comment: this was an uphill battle to get permissions for the TFS service account's user folder.

Comment: Deleting and recreating/configuring agents didn't work, but solution did work for us.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new Workspace with the following parameters :

- Owner : Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION)
- Permissions : Public workspace
- Name : same name as the deleted workspace

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm getting an error: "TF14045: The identity Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION) is not a recognized identity."

Comment: @TDN it works. If your TFS is localized you must localized the owner name. To find the localized name you can use the command `tf workspaces /computer:<AgentServer> /collection:<CollectionUrl>`
For instance the french one is: _Service de build de collection de projets (TEAM FOUNDATION)_

Comment: Our TFS server is not installed on our build server if that it was you meant as "localized TFS". From running the command as you suggested, I do not see the owner name that the build is complaining about.

Comment: @TDN by localized I mean that TFS is installed in a specific (non english) language. The command can be run from any computer with VS installed. The `<AgentServer>` is the name of the server where the TFS agent is installed.
What's the version of your TFS? Do you use TFVC as version control?

Answer (score 0):

TFS created a new workspace for me when I chose to copy the existing build definition. I simply deleted the original and then renamed the copied version back to the original name.

Answer (score 0):

As DaveShaw mentioned. Go to Repository tab and set clean to true, this will fix the issue.